# Keras network to handle two input images

Tags: keras

I want to use Keras CNN to classify images of coins. Each coin has two images (one per side), and I don't think it is a good idea to teach CNN on BOTH sides simultaneously.
So the question is, how to join two (identical but trained on different sides) CNNs, put a common fully connected classifier on them, and how to feed data to this construct (how to feed two images and make sure each half of a network gets its image).
Help appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your end goal for classification?

Comment: To recognize the kind of a coin. Like 25c 1997 vs 25c 1998 vs 50c 1999...

Comment: ... And to figure out how to "merge" networks that have common classifier.